# MFC casting Handle into pointer and DIB to DDB conversion

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create a bitmap by hardcoding an array of pixel values, converting this array of pixels into a DIB, and then turn this DIB into a DDB. I found two functions to convert CreateBitmapFromPixels and DIBToDDB on the internet. My problem is that the program would crash at line 244. I found that, at line 243, lpbi does not retrieve information from hDIB. Then I added the code at lines 229 and 230 to see if doing the same thing in the function that created the BITMAPINFO structure would help. Still, nothing was gotten from the HBITMAP. I am wondering if there is anything wrong with casting a handle into a pointer, what does it do, and are there other ways to get the HBITMAPINFOHEADER from a handle to a DIB so I can fix the problem.

```
 HBITMAP ColorChange2Dlg::CreateBitmapFromPixels( HDC hDC,
     UINT uWidth, UINT uHeight, UINT uBitsPerPixel, LPVOID pBits)
{
    if(uBitsPerPixel < 8) // NOT IMPLEMENTED YET
        return NULL;

    if(uBitsPerPixel == 8)
        return Create8bppBitmap(hDC, uWidth, uHeight, pBits);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = 0;
    if ( !uWidth || !uHeight || !uBitsPerPixel )
        return hBitmap;
    LONG lBmpSize = uWidth * uHeight * (uBitsPerPixel/8) ;
    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = { 0 };
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = uBitsPerPixel;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = uHeight;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = uWidth;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    if(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount==32)  {
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression=BI_RGB;
        //bmpInfo.bmiColors=NULL;
    }
        // Pointer to access the pixels of bitmap
    UINT * pPixels = 0;
    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection( hDC, (BITMAPINFO *)&
        bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&
        pPixels , NULL, 0);

    if ( !hBitmap )
        return hBitmap; // return if invalid bitmaps

    //SetBitmapBits( hBitmap, lBmpSize, pBits);
    // Directly Write
    memcpy(pPixels, pBits, lBmpSize );
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER lpbi;                                          //Line 229
    lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)hBitmap;                               //Line 230
    return hBitmap;
}

HBITMAP ColorChange2Dlg::DIBToDDB( HANDLE hDIB, CDC& dc ) 
{ 
    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER lpbi; 
    HBITMAP hbm; 
    CPalette pal; 
    CPalette* pOldPal; 
    //CClientDC dc(NULL); 
    if (hDIB == NULL) 
        return NULL; 
    lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)hDIB;                                           //Line 243
    int nColors = lpbi->biClrUsed ? lpbi->biClrUsed : 1 << lpbi->biBitCount;   //Line 244


    BITMAPINFO &bmInfo = *(LPBITMAPINFO)hDIB ; 
    LPVOID lpDIBBits; 
    if( bmInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount > 8 ) 
        lpDIBBits = (LPVOID)((LPDWORD)(bmInfo.bmiColors + 
        bmInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed) + 
        ((bmInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS) ? 3 : 0)); 
    else 
        lpDIBBits = (LPVOID)(bmInfo.bmiColors + nColors); 
    // Create and select a logical palette if needed 
    if( nColors <= 256 && dc.GetDeviceCaps(RASTERCAPS) & RC_PALETTE) 
    { 
        UINT nSize = sizeof(LOGPALETTE) + (sizeof(PALETTEENTRY) * nColors); 
        LOGPALETTE *pLP = (LOGPALETTE *) new BYTE[nSize]; 
        pLP->palVersion = 0x300; 
        pLP->palNumEntries = nColors; 
        for( int i=0; i < nColors; i++) 
        { 
            pLP->palPalEntry[i].peRed = bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbRed; 
            pLP->palPalEntry[i].peGreen = bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbGreen; 
            pLP->palPalEntry[i].peBlue = bmInfo.bmiColors[i].rgbBlue; 
            pLP->palPalEntry[i].peFlags = 0; 
        } 
        pal.CreatePalette( pLP ); 
        delete[] pLP; 
        // Select and realize the palette 
        pOldPal = dc.SelectPalette( &pal, FALSE ); 
        dc.RealizePalette(); 
    } 
    hbm = CreateDIBitmap(dc.GetSafeHdc(), // handle to device context 
        (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)lpbi, // pointer to bitmap info header 
        (LONG)CBM_INIT, // initialization flag 
        lpDIBBits, // pointer to initialization data 
        (LPBITMAPINFO)lpbi, // pointer to bitmap info 
        DIB_RGB_COLORS ); // color-data usage 
    if (pal.GetSafeHandle()) 
        dc.SelectPalette(pOldPal,FALSE); 
    return hbm; 
} 

void ColorChange2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CClientDC dc(this);
    COLORREF *pix = (COLORREF *)malloc(255*255*sizeof(COLORREF));
    //int x = 1;
    if(pix!=NULL){
        for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<255;j++)
            {
                pix[i*255+j] = RGB(i,j,0);
            }
        }
    }
    CDC tempDC;
    tempDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    HBITMAP dib = CreateBitmapFromPixels(tempDC.m_hDC,255,255,8*sizeof(COLORREF),(BYTE*)pix);
    HBITMAP finalMap = DIBToDDB(dib,tempDC);
    HBITMAP oldMap = (HBITMAP)tempDC.SelectObject(finalMap);
    dc.BitBlt(201,50,255,255,&tempDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    tempDC.SelectObject(oldMap);
    tempDC.DeleteDC();
}
```

Comment: `dc.GetDeviceCaps(RASTERCAPS) & RC_PALETTE` I think this code is for old display drivers. Modern computers support 32 bit colors. Images with 256 colors, or lower, contain their pixel information in `BITMAPINFO::bmpColors`. You don't have to manually call the palette functions because GDI functions know there is a palette. You should explain in more detail what it is you are trying to do (your overall goal?)

Comment: I want to create a 255 by 255 pixel bitmap where each pixel has a unique red and green color. (All pixels have 0 blue) I have heard that I have to use a DIB instead of DDB to set individual pixel colors. So I searched through the web and came up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write compatible code, it's better not to access bits directly at all. You can use Gradient functions and GDI or GDI+ draw functions to do anything you want.

The code you have in mind `pix[i*255+j] = RGB(i,j,0);` is of a 32-bit image. Each pixel points to a color. It's not a palette image where each pixel points to an entry in the color table.

If display is 32 bit (most modern computers are, but check to make sure), you can do this with the following code

```
CBitmap m_bitmap;
void CMyWnd::make_bitmap()
{
    if (m_bitmap.GetSafeHandle()) return;
    int w = 255; 
    int h = 255;
    int *pix = new int[w*h];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            pix[i + j*w] = RGB(i, j, 0);
    m_bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, 1, 32, pix);
    delete[]pix;
}
```

And to draw the bitmap:

```
void CMyWnd::paint_bitmap(CDC &dc)
{
    if (!m_bitmap.GetSafeHandle()) return;
    CDC memdc;
    memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    HBITMAP oldbitmap = (HBITMAP)memdc.SelectObject(m_bitmap);

    BITMAP bm;
    m_bitmap.GetBitmap(&bm);

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, &memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    memdc.SelectObject(oldbitmap);
}

void CMyWnd::OnPaint()
{
    __super::OnPaint();
    CClientDC dc(this);
    paint_bitmap(dc);
}
```

---

Edit: For historical reasons the RGB value are saved backward as BGR. Use this function instead:

```
void CMyWnd::make_bitmap()
{
    if (m_bitmap.GetSafeHandle()) return;

    int w = 256;
    int h = 256;
    BYTE *pix = new BYTE[4*w*h];

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            int p = (i + j*w) * 4;
            pix[p + 0] = 0;//blue
            pix[p + 1] = i;//green
            pix[p + 2] = j;//red
            pix[p + 3] = 0;//not used in GDI functions
        }
    }

    m_bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, 1, 32, pix);

    delete[]pix;
}
```

Comment: very interesting. I tinkered with your code and it worked. I had to call OnPaint right after delete[]pix; in CMyWnd::make_bitmap(); Is this OnPaint function different from CMyWnd::OnPaint?

Comment: `void OnPaint()` is reserved in MFC for handling `ON_WM_PAINT`, it should not be called directly.

Comment: Also the picture generated is a blue and green mixture instead of red and green

Comment: Yes you can use `Invalidate()` or `InvalidateRect` to force repaint. The colors red and blue are swapped. See edit...